# Why do I need to cast a dynamic object when calling IEnumerable.Contains()?

Tags: c#, dynamic, ienumerable, contains

I am trying to call `IEnumerable.Contains()` with a `dynamic` argument, but I am getting the error

> 'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Contains(IQueryable, TSource)' has some invalid arguments

I've noticed that I can either cast the argument to the correct type, or use an underlying collection type to fix the issue. But I'm not sure why I can't just pass in the argument directly.

```
dynamic d = "test";
var s = new HashSet<string>();
IEnumerable<string> ie = s;

s.Contains(d);           // Works
ie.Contains(d);          // Does not work
ie.Contains((string)d);  // Works
```

Comment: @JonSkeet if I remove it, it throws error in my vs2012 no biggie

Comment: I may have had a typo @JonSkeet I will remove the comment to eliminate any confusion

Comment: @JonSkeet I have removed ..thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Enumerable.Contains` is an extension method - and extension methods aren't resolved by the mini-compiler which is used at execution time. (Extension methods depend on `using` directives, which aren't preserved. They could be, but I guess that was seen as a bit painful.) This includes both using `dynamic` arguments to extension methods, *and* on using them as the "target" of extension methods.

Just specify the extension method directly instead:

```
var result = Enumerable.Contains(ie, d);
```

Comment: This works on this [online compiler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xPvF8e).

Comment: @ryanyuyu no it doesn't it throws an error notice the squiggly red line when you hover over `b = ie.Contains(d);` when clicking on the link

Comment: @MethodMan and notice that was the OP's original code producing the squiggly.  Jon Skeet's solution does not produce an error.